# SQL query hangs on join

Tags: sql, join, timeout, ora-01652

I've written an SQL query that produces a report of some stats for each **Year-Week-Mine-Product**.

It works exactly as desired except for one thing - **trn.wid-date** isn't the correct date to be using.

I should be using **td.datetime-act-comp-dump**. When I replace **trn.wid-date** with **td.datetime-act-comp-dump**, it doesn't give me any errors but seems to just hang indefinitely. I let it go for a while yesterday and it came back with ORA-01652 unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP, though I haven't seen that error since.

I don't understand what might be causing that considering that I'm able to successfully return **MAX(td.datetime-act-comp-dump)** in the query below

```
select to_char(trn.wid_date, 'IYYY') as dump_year,
       to_char(trn.wid_date-7/24, 'IW') as dump_week,
       SUBSTR(trn.train_control_id,1,2) as Mine,
       vcon.product_type_code as Product,
       COUNT(DISTINCT trn.train_control_id) as Trains,
       COUNT(1) as Wagons,
       MIN(trn.wid_date) as Min_WID_Hrs,
       MAX(trn.wid_date) as Max_WID_Hrs,
       MIN(td.datetime_act_comp_dump) as Min_Fin_Dump,
       MAX(td.datetime_act_comp_dump) as Max_Fin_Dump,        
       ROUND(SUM(con.weight_total-con.empty_weight_total),0) as Tot_Tonnes,       
       ROUND(AVG(con.weight_total-con.empty_weight_total),2) as Avg_Tonnes,
       ROUND(MIN(con.weight_total-con.empty_weight_total),2) as Minimum,
       ROUND(PERCENTILE_DISC(0.99) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY (con.weight_total-con.empty_weight_total) DESC),2) as "1st",      

from  widsys.consist con
      INNER JOIN widsys.train trn
      USING (train_record_id)
      INNER JOIN tpps.train_details td
      ON trn.train_tpps_id||trn.mine_code = td.train_id||td.mine_code
      INNER JOIN widsys.v_consist_ore_detail vcon
      USING (consist_id)

where trn.direction = 'N'
      and to_char(trn.wid_date, 'IYYY') = 2009
      and to_char(trn.wid_date-7/24, 'IW') = 25

group by to_char(trn.wid_date, 'IYYY'),
         to_char(trn.wid_date-7/24, 'IW'),
         SUBSTR(trn.train_control_id,1,2),
         vcon.product_type_code

order by to_char(trn.wid_date-7/24, 'IW') DESC
```

Just in order to troubleshoot, from the query above, I've tried removing everything to do with **vcon** and replacing **trn.wid_date** with **td.datetime-act-comp-dump**. The effect is that it only reports on **Year-Week-Mine** rather than **Year-Week-Mine-Product**. (see query below)

This new query actually executes rather than just hanging, but returns a few odd results and doesn't isn't sufficient since it doesn't break things down on Product.

```
select to_char(td.datetime_act_comp_dump, 'IYYY') as dump_year,
       to_char(td.datetime_act_comp_dump-7/24, 'IW') as dump_week,
       SUBSTR(trn.train_control_id,1,2) as Mine,
       --vcon.product_type_code as Product,
       COUNT(DISTINCT trn.train_control_id) as Trains,
       COUNT(1) as Wagons,
       MIN(trn.wid_date) as Min_WID_Hrs,
       MAX(trn.wid_date) as Max_WID_Hrs,
       MIN(td.datetime_act_comp_dump) as Min_Fin_Dump,
       MAX(td.datetime_act_comp_dump) as Max_Fin_Dump,        
       ROUND(SUM(con.weight_total-con.empty_weight_total),0) as Tot_Tonnes,       
       ROUND(AVG(con.weight_total-con.empty_weight_total),2) as Avg_Tonnes,
       ROUND(MIN(con.weight_total-con.empty_weight_total),2) as Minimum,
       ROUND(PERCENTILE_DISC(0.99) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY (con.weight_total-con.empty_weight_total) DESC),2) as "1st"       

from  widsys.consist con
      INNER JOIN widsys.train trn
      USING (train_record_id)
      INNER JOIN tpps.train_details td
      ON trn.train_tpps_id||trn.mine_code = td.train_id||td.mine_code
      --INNER JOIN widsys.v_consist_ore_detail vcon
      --USING (consist_id)

where trn.direction = 'N'
      and to_char(td.datetime_act_comp_dump, 'IYYY') = 2009
      and to_char(td.datetime_act_comp_dump-7/24, 'IW') = 25

group by to_char(td.datetime_act_comp_dump, 'IYYY'),
         to_char(td.datetime_act_comp_dump-7/24, 'IW'),
         SUBSTR(trn.train_control_id,1,2)
         --vcon.product_type_code

order by to_char(td.datetime_act_comp_dump-7/24, 'IW') DESC
```

Any advice on what might be going wrong?

Cheers,

Tommy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to run muuuuuuuch faster by creating a subquery for widsys tables and one for tpps tables. Then doing an implicit inner join on two columns instead of concatenating.

```
SELECT blah FROM (widsys subquery) w, (tpps subquery) t WHERE w.mine_code = t.mine_code and w.train_id = t.train_tpps_id
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that I can think of without more information is that the `datetime_act_comp_dump` column of `train_details` isn't indexed and `wid_date` is. This sounds like a pretty normal performance issue where something is not indexed or the `train` and `train_details` tables are dramatically different sizes and your join is blowing up.

I'm not sure which DB you are using, but you might want to figure out how to run the query execution plan profiler and see what the difference between the two execution plans are. I suspect that the answer is going to be something structural or maybe that the concatenation in the join statement is causing some DB-specific problems.